# can C++ template detect members of specific type?

Tags: c++

can C++ template detect members of specific type? As code below,

```
template <typename T>
class Element {

};

template <typename T>
class Container {
 public:
  Container() {
    // check if T has member which type is "Element<whatever>"
    // how many Element<whatever>s?
    // offset?
  }
};
```

I have a template class named `Container`, and I want to check:

1. If the passed in type `T` has member which type is `Element<whatever>`?
2. If so, can I get how many members which type is `Element<whatever>`?
3. If so, can I get the offset to the beginning of the class?

Explain more about requirement 3:

What I want is to access these fields(if exist) when I get a piece of data which is cast by `reinterpret_cast<T>`

Comment: No, it is not possible. What you are asking for is known as compile-time reflection, which is not yet in c++.

Comment: It might be cleaner to have 2 templates anyway, TFoo and TElementsFoo for classes that are elemental.

Comment: You can check for the existence of a member given that you know it's name beforehand. What you are asking is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is doable in C++20 if the `T` of `Container<T>` is an aggregate ; I use the boost::pfr library as it simplifies this idiom but it is easily reimplementable by hand (boost::pfr's source is very simple to read)

```cpp
#include <boost/pfr.hpp>

template<typename T, typename Target>
auto count_members_of_type()
{
   unsigned int count = 0;
   boost::pfr::for_each_field<T>(T{}, [&] <typename U> (U&&) {
       count += std::is_same_v<std::remove_reference_t<U>, Target>;
   });
   return count;
}
```

given

```
struct Foo {
  Element<int> a, b;
  Element<float> c;
  std::string d;
};
```

then

```
count_members_of_type<Foo, Element<int>>() == 2
```

Running example on gcc.godbolt.org: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/srhn8GfWb